# Capturar nome do usuário logado na máquina via Aplicação Web

Tags: javascript, java, aplicação-web, active-directory

Existem duas aplicações, uma em Java e outra em ASP e ambas conseguem fazer integração com Active Directory sem que eu digite usuário e senha de rede. 
A aplicação feita utilizando ASP, loga automaticamente ao acessar a url, porém não funciona no Firefox e eu tenho que digitar usuário e senha.
A aplicação feita em Java, eu seleciono uma opção e o login é feito de forma automática.

**Dúvidas**

Como posso capturar o nome do usuário logado sem Applet ou Controle Activex? Javascript? Sempre achei que pegar o usuário da máquina só era possível com Applet ou Controle Activex

---

Observações: Existem perguntas semelhantes, mas é para fazer integração via linguagem.
Não tenho o código fonte das duas aplicações para verificar como é feito, e já analise pelo Chrome Dev Tools e não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, uma vez que o javascript não tem acesso direto ao sistema operacional. Apenas seria possível se você tiver um script server-side rodando no seu cliente, e pelo javascript você faça uma requisição ajax e obtenha esse valor.

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage que pode ser utilizada em vários navegadores. Ou armazenar como qualquer outra variável pelo checkbox mesmo no seu código php com opção de salvar, criando um botão com a opção de lembrá-la.

Comment: Li sobre o Local Storage, mas este não resolve o problema uma vez que eu preciso saber o nome do usuário que está logado na maquina. E preciso que seja feito através do browser.